# pass value from ngOnInit to template

Tags: angular, ngoninit

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  sub: any;
  lang: string;

constructor(public translate: TranslateService, public route: ActivatedRoute, private languageService: LanguageService) { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(p => {
        let lang = p['lang'];
        this.lang = lang;
    });

    this.languageService.translate.use(this.lang);
}
}
```

and in template i have this link

```
<a [routerLink]="['en']">test</a>
```

How can I pass value from ngOnInit to that routeLink? for example I want something like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="[(lang)]">test</a>
```

but it's undefined. in ngOnInit it has value

Comment: Isn't `<a [routerLink]="lang">test</a>` working for you?

Comment: nah anyway undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lang` really is not undefined you should just be able to do this in your template:

`<a routerLink="{{lang}}">test</a>`

or

`<a [routerLink]="lang">test</a>`

Check with `console.log(lang)` in your ngOnInit, if it really is set, first.